# Checking for existence in a string with strpos

Tags: php, strpos

I've only ever seen developers use strict comparisons when they use `strpos` to check for the existence of a substring:

```
if (strpos($haystack,$needle) !== false) {

}
```

It occurred to me today that one *could* use `is_numeric` ins

```
if (is_numeric(strpos($haystack,$needle))) {

}
```

Is there a reason one would use one over the other (specifically in this use case)?

If you think about it, the purpose of `strpos` is to return the *position* of the substring.  Only if it doesn't exist, will it return false.  The position is a *number*.  Thus, `is_numeric` is pretty qualified to be considered semantically.

Comment: is_numeric will return true on both strings and intergers

Comment: I had the same thought as this, except using `is_int( )` not `is_numeric( )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this question searching for almost the same question, except my thought was to use `is_int( )` not `is_numeric( )`. I couldn't really understand the benchmark that was posted so I made my own. In short, `is_numeric( )` is a hair slower than `!== false`, and `is_int( )` is a hair faster. Personally, I find it more readable than `!== false` not less, so I'll probably switch to it.

This was done under php v7.1.23

Results:

```
0.7900s for '!== false' with hits
4.5137s for '!== false' with misses

0.9297s for 'is_numeric' with hits
4.7509s for 'is_numeric' with misses

0.6391s for 'is_int' with hits
4.4862s for 'is_int' with misses
```

From the code:

```
$n_times = 10000000;
$haystack_hit = "  Certificate Name: example.com";
$heystack_miss = "Found the following certs:";
$needle = "Certificate Name:";

$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < $n_times; $i++)
    {
    if (strpos($haystack_hit,$needle) !== false)
        { }
    }
$end = microtime(true) - $start;
echo "\n" . round($end,4) . "s for '!== false' with hits\n";

$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < $n_times; $i++)
    {
    if (strpos($haystack_miss,$needle) !== false)
        { }
    }
$end = microtime(true) - $start;
echo round($end,4) . "s for '!== false' with misses\n\n";

// -----

$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < $n_times; $i++)
    {
    if ( is_numeric(strpos($haystack_hit,$needle)) )
        { }
    }
$end = microtime(true) - $start;
echo round($end,4) . "s for 'is_numeric' with hits\n";

$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < $n_times; $i++)
    {
    if ( is_numeric(strpos($haystack_miss,$needle)) )
        { }
    }
$end = microtime(true) - $start;
echo round($end,4) . "s for 'is_numeric' with misses\n\n";

// -----

$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < $n_times; $i++)
    {
    if ( is_int(strpos($haystack_hit,$needle)) )
        { }
    }
$end = microtime(true) - $start;
echo round($end,4) . "s for 'is_int' with hits\n";

$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < $n_times; $i++)
    {
    if ( is_int(strpos($haystack_miss,$needle)) )
        { }
    }
$end = microtime(true) - $start;
echo round($end,4) . "s for 'is_int' with misses\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

I've created a benchmark. Case `check by compare with false value` always faster than `check by is_numeric`.

```
// Init a big string array

for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++){
$str[] = 'a'.rand().'b'.rand();
}

// Case comparing with false value
$time1 = microtime(true);
foreach($str as $st){
$res[] = strpos($st,rand(0, count(array('b', 'c')) - 1 )) !== false;
}
$time2 = microtime(true);

echo $time2-$time1.'<br/>';

// Case 'is_numeric'
$time3 = microtime(true);
foreach($str as $st){
$res[] = is_numeric(strpos($st,rand(0, count(array('b', 'c')) - 1 )));
}
$time4 = microtime(true);
echo $time4-$time3;


//Time 1: 
//0.018877029418945 
//0.020556926727295

//Time 2:
//0.016352891921997
//0.016934871673584

//Time 3:
//0.0121009349823
//0.01330304145813

//Time 4:
//0.017507076263428
//0.01904296875
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `strpos` returns either integer or boolean false it's okay to use `is_numeric`.
The question is:
What is more **idiomatic** and **autodocumented/self-descriptive**, using `is_numeric` or comparing return value to boolean? IMO, comparing to boolean false is much more intuitive:

```
$string = 'new object';
$found = strpos($string,'new');

echo (is_numeric($found)) ? 'found' : 'not found';
echo "\n";
# much better
echo ($found !== false)   ? 'found' : 'not found';
echo "\n";
```

Also, `strpos(...) !== false` is overused because it's what PHP documentation suggests. Thus it has become conventional.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using strpos in this context is for is greater speed over preg_match, using is_numeric on top of it is negating this speed advantage by adding more overhead.
2. Using another function just to separate false from the rest makes no sense, better just use !== false

There is no reason why would anybody use is_numeric, but it will work, only slower.

About strpos vs preg_match:
[preg_match() vs strpos() for match finding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433492/preg-match-vs-strpos-for-match-finding) and 
[which is the fast process strpos()/stripos() or preg_match() in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477984/which-is-the-fast-process-strpos-stripos-or-preg-match-in-php)

Comment: But is it really slower?

Comment: Using two function is slower than using one.

Comment: That not make sense. Morover, that is just  [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: There's still computing power needed to process a `===` (or similar) comparison. One function for one comparison is likely little to no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `is_numeric` works with `strpos`. But this can make the code tricky, hence lowering code readability.

Have in mind that although this may seems obvious to you, you are making another programmer that reads your code think in a lot of things:

1. Does the haystack contains the needle?
2. Which is the position of the needle in the haystack?
3. What type of value does strpos returns?
4. Is the returned value of strpos a number in this case?

And PHP can be quite a *tricky language* by itself, take a look at this examples:

```
if (strpos("needle in a haystack","needle")!==false) {
    echo "Needle found!<br>";
} else {
    echo "nothing found<br>";
}

if (is_numeric(strpos("needle in a haystack","needle"))) {
    echo "Needle found!<br>";
} else {
    echo "nothing found<br>";
}

if (is_int(strpos("needle in a haystack","needle"))) {
    echo "Needle found!<br>";
} else {
    echo "nothing found<br>";
}

// This doesn't work since 0 == false is true
if (strpos("needle in a haystack","needle")!=false) {
    echo "Needle found!<br>";
} else {
    echo "nothing found<br>";
}

// But this works since "haystack" position is not 0
if (strpos("needle in a haystack","haystack")!=false) {
    echo "Haystack found!<br>";
} else {
    echo "nothing found<br>";
}

// This doesn't work also because "needle" is at 0, and 0 is not a truthy value
if (strpos("needle in a haystack","needle")) {
    echo "Needle found!<br>";
} else {
    echo "nothing found<br>";
}

// But this works again since "haystack" position is not 0, and any int that's not 0 is truthy
if (strpos("needle in a haystack","haystack")) {
    echo "Haystack found!<br>";
} else {
    echo "nothing found<br>";
}
```

Imho, the best option is using `===false` and `==!false` comparisons, like explained in [the php documentation for strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> **Warning**
>   This function may return Boolean **FALSE**, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

**PD:** For a better definition of "truthy" take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693876/how-exactly-does-ifvariable-work).