# Laravel 5.5 - Check if string contains exact words

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

In laravel, I have a `$string` and a `$blacklistArray`

```
$string = 'Cassandra is a clean word so it should pass the check';
$blacklistArray = ['ass','ball sack'];

$contains = str_contains($string, $blacklistArray); // true, contains bad word
```

The result of `$contains` is true, so this will be flagged as containing a black list word (which is not correct). This is because the name below partially contains `ass`

C**ass**andra

However, this is a partial match and `Cassandra` is not a bad word, so it should not be flagged. Only if a word in the string is an exact match, should it be flagged.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Use preg_match or similar_text

Comment: This might be an interesting read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter

Comment: maybe a solution convert "$string" to array object and then check

Comment: @DiegoCespedes Not sure what you mean, do you mind posting an answer to test it with your possible solution?

Comment: Rephrase this question to make it helpful! "Cassandra" and "ass" for the srting " Cassandra is a clean word so it should pass the check" should be flagged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$blacklistArray = array('ass','ball sack');

$string = 'Cassandra is a clean word so it should pass the check';



$matches = array();
$matchFound = preg_match_all(
                "/\b(" . implode($blacklistArray,"|") . ")\b/i", 
                $string, 
                $matches
              );

// if it find matches bad words

if ($matchFound) {
  $words = array_unique($matches[0]);
  foreach($words as $word) {

    //show bad words found
    dd($word);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 13):

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-contains

The `str_contains` function determines if the given string contains the given value:

```
$contains = str_contains('This is my name', 'my');
```

You may also pass an array of values to determine if the given string contains any of the values:

```
$contains = str_contains('This is my name', ['my', 'foo']);
```

Comment: Thank you for jumping in. I understand how it's used from my question, but I was after partial matches issue.

Comment: The second way doesn't work for me, it says `TypeError: Argument 2 passed to str_contains() must be of the type string or null, array given on line 1`. It works for you? I am on laravel 5.8

Comment: $contains =  Str::contains('This is my name', ['my', 'foo']);

Answer (score 4):

Laravel `Str::contains()` method can check values against a work. Don't forget to `use Illuminate\Support\Str;`

Works on Laravel 7.x

Also accepts arrays of value. Instance:

$string = 'Cassandra is a clean word so it should pass the check';
$blacklistArray = ['ass','ball sack'];

```
if(Str::contains($string, $blacklistArray)){return true;}

// returns true
```

May not be your exact request though

Answer (score 2):

`str_contains()` works with strings - not with arrays, but you can loop it:

```
$string = 'Cassandra is a clean word so it should pass the check';
$blacklistArray = ['ass','ball sack'];

$flag = false;
foreach ($blacklistArray as $k => $v) {
    if str_contains($string, $v) {
        $flag = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($flag == true) {
    // someone was nasty
}
```

Comment: is there a way to rewrite this as an array_map instead of a foreach?

Comment: Thank you for this, I went with Diego since he commented on the issue earlier as well. Don't know why, but I prefer `array_map` over `foreach`. Upvoted :)

Comment: I would go with @set0x 's solution. Except you are doing some kind of sociological/psychological/behavioral research, I can't imagine why would you need list of words tried by user.

Comment: It is just to stop certain bad words from certain fields.

Comment: @set0x 's answer is your thing. `str_contains()` uses `mb_strpos()` funtion which is much faster than regular expression and you need just flag if any unwanted word was used. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477984/which-is-the-fast-process-strpos-stripos-or-preg-match-in-php) is a bit old now, but can give you idea of functions' speed.

Comment: But `if str_contains($string, $v) {` The `Cassandra` in the `$string`, when `$v` is `ass` will flag someone was nasty, when they were not.

Comment: You are right. I overlooked that case. Then you have to use preg_match. :)

Answer (score 0):

> str_contains($body, $search) -  Works to find a string within a string.
>
> Illuminate\Support\Str::contains($body, $search) - Works exactly as PHP
> str_contains(), but it supports array values also as '$search'

But in both cases, it is a partial search, which means

```
str_contains('consent', 'sent') //true
```

`Illuminate\Support\Str::contains('consent', 'sent') //true`

If we use regular expression we can achieve this. Following is the function I used in my project:

```
function is_word_contains($needle,$haystack,$i,$word) {
     // $i should be "" or "i" for case insensitive
    if (strtoupper($word)=="W")
    {   // if $word is "W" then word search instead of string in string search.
        // echo "/\b{$needle}\b/{$i}";
        if (preg_match("/\b{$needle}\b/{$i}", $haystack)) 
        {                
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(preg_match("/{$needle}/{$i}", $haystack)) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    // Put quotes around true and false above to return them as strings instead of as bools/ints.
}
```